# Installing .net 8 rc2 on ubuntu 22.02

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, azure-devops

I was able to get .net 7 installed very easily with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#scripted-install) documentation and microsoft's install script.

However, this Ubuntu instance is a build agent that needs to run compilation of .net 8 rc2 projects, along with EF core whose tooling must also be at a preview version.

I can't seem to figure out how to get it installed because I've tried:

1. Running `tar zxf "$DOTNET_FILE" -C "/usr/lib/dotnet/sdk/8.0.100-rc.2.23502.2"` to extract the downloaded SDK and install it where my .net 7 install is at. It works but subsequent calls to install EF tooling fails saying that it can't find dotnet.dll in the 8.0.100 folder.
2. Running `./dotnet-install.sh --version 8.0.100-rc.2.23502.2` which completes but never showed up in `dotnet --list-sdks`

Dotnet 8 will probably release at DOTNET Conf 2023 and with it an official installer will probably come out, but why is this so hard and what is the actual way to install pre-release SDKs on a build agent in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After untar the downloaded package of .NET 8, you also need to add the installation path of .NET 8 into the system **`PATH`**. For more details, see "[**.NET 8 installation instructions for Linux**](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/8.0/install-linux.md)".

See below example as reference.

1. If you can manually sign in the Ubuntu agent, try to manually execute the command lines below under the directory you want to install .NET 8.

   ```bash
   wget "https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/9144f37e-b370-41ee-a86f-2d2a69251652/bc1d544112ec134184a5aec7f7a1eaf9/dotnet-sdk-8.0.100-rc.2.23502.2-linux-x64.tar.gz"
   mkdir dotnet8
   tar -xzvf dotnet-sdk-8.0.100-rc.2.23502.2-linux-x64.tar.gz -C dotnet8
   rm dotnet-sdk-8.0.100-rc.2.23502.2-linux-x64.tar.gz
   export DOTNET_ROOT=~/dotnet8
   export PATH=$PATH:~/dotnet8
   ```
2. If your Ubuntu agent is built from a Docker image, you can add below step in the associated Dockerfile. Then use the updated Dockerfile to build a new image.

   ```
   # Install .NET 8
   RUN wget "https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/9144f37e-b370-41ee-a86f-2d2a69251652/bc1d544112ec134184a5aec7f7a1eaf9/dotnet-sdk-8.0.100-rc.2.23502.2-linux-x64.tar.gz" \
       && mkdir dotnet8 \
       && tar -xzvf dotnet-sdk-8.0.100-rc.2.23502.2-linux-x64.tar.gz -C dotnet8 \
       && rm dotnet-sdk-8.0.100-rc.2.23502.2-linux-x64.tar.gz \
       && mv dotnet8 /usr/share/ \
       && update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/dotnet" "dotnet" "/usr/share/dotnet8/dotnet" 1 \
       && update-alternatives --set dotnet /usr/share/dotnet8/dotnet
   ```

---

**EDIT:**

Another way is using the [**Use .NET Core task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/use-dotnet-v2?view=azure-pipelines) in your pipeline to install the specified version of .NET SDK.

```yaml
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 8.0.x'
  inputs:
    version: 8.0.x
    includePreviewVersions: true
```

[image]

Comment: Does it have to go into my home directory? I see my dotnet7 instance was put into `/usr/lib/dotnet/sdk` folder. I did everything you said except I was in that directory instead. And I set my paths to `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/dotnet/sdk/dotnet8` instead. Yet `dotnet --list-sdks` doesn't show the new version. Even after a logout and reboot.

Comment: I repeated but this time in home directory and still no response showing the dotnet 8 sdk. Is it possible the /usr/lib location of being 'found' first? FWIW -- This is the base Ubuntu that comes with Windows 10 hyper-v.

Comment: @Killnine, I have updated my above answer with more suggestions. Check and try it.

Comment: I'm actually doing that now, thanks. The reason I have to go through this on the agent is because I need to install the EF core tooling and, by only having .net 7 installed, I couldn't install the .net8-compatible version. (ex: `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 8.0.0-rc.2.23480.1`)

Comment: I tried by loading into just `/usr/lib/dotnet` (instead of including /sdk) and it worked!